# NAT and P2P router crash

Tags: crash, nat, p2p

So..i had this argument with my networks teacher. He said that some people complains about router crashes due to many entrys on NAT tables on a router.

I didnt understand and i asked: "If the application uses the same port, why does the router crash?. It should have only one entry (pc-ip,pcport;public-ip,public-port)". And he said: "it doesnt matter its using the same port".

I got the idea that NAT creates an entry for every packet that passes trought it. Iam assuming NAT with overloading as you might have guessed.

So the questions are:

1. How does nat entrys are created? On a packet basis or connection basis? I mean: suppose i send a udp packet..does the router create an entry?
2. When i start a TCP connection, does the router create a persistant nat entry until the connection closes?
3. Was my teacher right? The NAT table can overload assuming an aplication on the same port sending packets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running nmap against a large subnet can easily overflow the state table on cheap routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Per connection (or per UDP stream)
2. Yes
3. Yes. For example, your web-browser on one internal PC can have multiple simultaneous TCP connections open concurrently to each of several different external web servers. For each connection the source-port will vary (chosen randomly) but the destination port and destination IP-address may be identical for several connections. A router designed to serve the needs of two or three computers in a home might be unable to cope with the number of simultaneous connections needed in (for example) a school with perhaps hundreds of very busy computers. Routers have to be sized for the expected load.

---

If you look at [example C source for TCP client](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c) described in [Howto](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm), you will see that the "sockets" API does not provide any means for the client initiating a connection to specify a source-port.

Comment: You can't open 100 connections with the same source-port if the destination address and port are the same. A typical web server only listens on port 80 so all HTTP connections to that server will have destination-port=80. Each connection **must** have a unique combination of source-address x source port x destination address x destination port. When you initiate a connection, the operating chooses a random, unused, source-port for you.

Comment: So, if my browser starts 100 hundred connections from port 1300 to the same web server, the NAT table will create 100 entrys with(source-ip,1300;public-source, externalport) where external port will vary 100 times while the the rest of the fields are exactly the same?

Comment: As I said, your browser cannot do that.

Comment: Sorry, i was correcting one thing. Ok what if my browser starts 100 connections to 100 different ips, will the NAT table fill 100 entrys with (source-ip,1300;public-source, externalport)

Comment: whre source-ip, public-source are the same but the external port varies?

Comment: See [RFC793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) especially section 2.7

Comment: I forgot the concept of ip pair identifier, but my main question is not completly answered: considering a browser that starts many connections from port 1300 to diferente ips. In this case the 4 tuple (sourceip,sourceport,destip,dest port) is different because the destination ip is diferent, but the source ip,port and destination port are the same on all connections. When i start a connection, a nat entry will be filled. When i start another connection from the same source, will the NAT table have another entry that is similar to the previous one but with different external port?

Comment: Re number of NAT table entries: See point one of my answer. Re port  1300: see final paragraph of answer.